# Are there any Java APIs allowing to make applications on top of Cardano?

Tags: api, language, java, sdk

cf. title of the question, is there a Java API to make Cardano developers ?

Comment: Welcome to our community! I recommend you add more detail to your question, simply because it's very unusual for the question body to just be a repeat of the question title. Perhaps you could say a bit about your overall goals with such an API or the motivation for why want this, or if you prefer open-source vs proprietary, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, try [cardano-client-lib](https://github.com/bloxbean/cardano-client-lib) SDK written in Java.